# Why is there a strange white space inside my div after setting its height and width to 0?

Tags: html, css

```html
<div style=" height:0;
               width: 0 ;
               border: 1px solid black ; ">
```

This is all the code
[image: code in chrome]

And as you can see there is a strange white space inside my div  . There should be a perfect black square  but there is not . When i run this same code on firefox i get a black square without any empty space inside . As you can see in the image there is no overriding css . I have cleared my cache and set chrome settings to default but it did not worked . PLEASE explain what is happening and also tell whether you have a perfect black square or not .

Comment: I see a black square unless I zoom in the browser (Which is likely due to rounding errors in the renderer) Is there a reason you need to use border, rather than just a background and a set size? (2px width and height would give the same result as a 1px border when there's no content)

Comment: @DBS  Yes that is my question DBS . You see  a Perfect black Square but I SEE a black square with white space inside it as shown in the image . Why is that so ? No there is not a reason for all this , its just that I am not able to understand what is happening here but I want to .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code locally and I am not seeing any whitespace inside the `div` but when I zoomed in on my browser page I can see whitespace inside the `div`. The solution is for you to reset your browser zoom to `normal` or `100%` in the browser settings to avoid seeing the space apart from that everything is working well.

Comment: This is strange . I  see no whitespace at 400% , 200% and less than 100% . But why is that so . Can you please explain .

Comment: I think the only explanation for that is that you assigned `border: 1px solid #000` to an empty `div`, this creates a line around it in the browser, and the only way this space inside the `div` can be seen is when you zoomed in your browser.

Comment: Thanks  for your time .

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the div tag. What I would suggest is to apply the styles in the css - not as inline styles.

```css
div {
  height:0;
  width: 0;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

I would also question why you have a border on a div that is height and width 0. You can set the styles and apply classes that then shave the div as you want it.

```css
.normal-height {
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 border: solid 1px black;
}

.no-height {
 height: 0;
 width: 0;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="normal-height"></div>
<hr/>
<div class="no-height"></div>
```

Comment: I forgot to do so . But still there is this strange white space inside my div as shown in the image . Please help .

Answer (score 0):

As you can see if you remove the height factor we cannot see any of the blank space if you want you can try it out

Hope it will be helpful

```html
<div style=" width: 0 ;
               border: 1px solid black ; ">
<\div>
```